# Highchart: Stacked Column replacement for setExtremes(min, max)

Tags: highcharts

With a big load of data in the highchart, chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max) seems to take too much time. I wonder if I can set the extremes directly at the creation of the chart, for example when I define the xAxis:

```
xAxis: [{
    categories: periods
}],
```

How can I do that? I don't find anything in the reference api.

Comment: Does it work? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min

Comment: @IgorShastin Do not edit the question, post a new answer instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [xAxis.min](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min) & [xAxis.max](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.max) properties.